# Android: how to split a screen for a TableLayout next to a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, tablelayout

How can I split the screen so that the left half of the screen is a Linearlayout and the right half is a Tablelayout.

I've tried applying a layout_weight of 1 to both and a weightSum of 2 to the RelativeLayout wrapper.

Can anyone guide me?

This is what I got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:text="@string/hello2" />
</LinearLayout>
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/Row1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    >
<TableRow>
<Button android:id="@+id/Modus" 
        android:text="@string/Mode1"
        android:background="@layout/modus_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />
<Button android:id="@+id/Modus" 
        android:text="@string/Mode2"
        android:background="@layout/modus_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a RelativeLayout as the wrapper? Also, when i tried to replicate what you had in Eclipse, i was told that the layout_weight attribute was invalid in a RelativeLayout. Try using a horizonal LinearLayout as the wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

Give an id to your LinearLayout and add `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/your_linear_layout"` parameter to your TableLayout. Or you may use another LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout. If you don't need to add more views LinearLayout could be better.